# Как программно узнать, есть ли у метода xml-комментарий?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

делаю Unit тесты для своей программы и хотел бы узнать, можно ли добавить проверку на существование комментария `/// <summary>`  у метода?

Comment: Комментарии не вшиваются в сборку, они лежат в отдельном xml файле рядом со сборкой. Так что чисто технически у метода их никогда нет. Можно открыть этот файл и распарить - там достаточно простой формат.

Comment: Но это точно не стоит делать в виде юнит теста. Юнит тесты должны проверять поведение, а не наличие комментов

Comment: @PashaPash а каким образом предложите проводить тестирование наличия этих комментариев? Можно ли делать проверку в swagger?

Comment: Скорее всего Вам нужно посмотреть в сторону статических анализаторов.

Comment: Есть вот такая штука https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1591, но там вроде надо специальный флаг компилятору добавлять.

Comment: @aepot оно раньше само по умолчанию спамило предупреждениями, если генерация xml была включена. может быть поменялось что-то

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. При подключении сервиса swagger указать путь до автоматически сгенерированного файла с документацией проекта.
2. С помощью `XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(SwaggerFile);` получить файл с комментариями к swagger.
3. Можно расспарсить его следующим образом:

```
                   .Element("members")
                   .Elements("member")
                   .Where(element => element.Attribute("name").Value.EndsWith("Controller"))
                   .Select(element => new ControlClassWithDescription
                   {
                       Name = element.Attribute("name").Value,
                       SummaryExist = element.Element("summary") != null,
                   });
```

Предварительно создав класс `ControlClassWithDescription` .

4. Проверить в цикле все ли файлы с контроллерами есть в списке.